# tKinter entry prints nothing

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, tk-toolkit, tkinter-entry

I'm creating an application using tktinter in python. I created a button called 'New Task' which calls a upon a function where the user can enter in a link, i then created another button, where another function is called upon, where the link the user inputtedis printed out in the console, but for some reason it prints nothing every time. Please help, Heres the code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import tkinter as tk              
LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)


class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (Task,LoginPage):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column = 0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(Task)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        #for frame in self.frames.values():
            #frame.grid_remove()

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
        frame.winfo_toplevel().geometry("1024x720")
        frame.configure(bg='#333130')
class LoginPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text=" Page 1", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        #loggedin(self, parent, controller)
class Task(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        c = Canvas(self, height=50, width=102400, bg="#333130")
        c.pack()
        homebutton = tk.Button(self, text='Home', command=lambda: controller.show_frame(HypeExtractor))
        homebutton_window = c.create_window(10, 12.5, anchor=tk.NW, window=homebutton)
        taskbutton = tk.Button(self, text='Task', command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Task))
        taskbutton_window = c.create_window(104, 12.5, anchor=tk.NW, window=taskbutton)
        adressbutton = tk.Button(self, text='Your Adressess', command=lambda: controller.show_frame(YourAdressess))
        adressbutton_window = c.create_window(196, 12.5, anchor=tk.NW, window=adressbutton)
        paymentbutton = tk.Button(self, text='Payment', command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Payment))
        paymentbutton_window = c.create_window(323, 12.5, anchor=tk.NW, window=paymentbutton)
        newtaskbutton = tk.Button(self, text='New Task',command=lambda: taskcreator())
        newtaskbutton_window = c.create_window(600, 12.5, anchor=tk.NE, window=newtaskbutton)
        #endtaskbutton = tk.Button(self, text='End Task', command=lambda: taskcreator())
        #endtaskbuttonn_window = c.create_window(690, 12.5, anchor=tk.NE, window=endtaskbutton)
        RunningTask = tk.Label(self, text='Running Task').place(x=10,y=75,anchor=tk.NW)

        #canvas = Canvas(self, width=60, height=60)
        #canvas.place(x=10, y=30)

def taskcreator():
    global screen
    screen = Tk()
    thelink = StringVar()
    screen.geometry('720x640')
    Label(screen, text='Enter Shoe Link').place(x=10, y=20)
    linkentry = Entry(screen, textvariable=thelink)
    linkentry.place(x=10, y=40)
    you = Button(screen, text='End Task', command=lambda: assign(thelink))
    you.pack()
    screen.mainloop()

def assign(thelink):
    link = thelink.get()

    # print(llink.get())
    print(thelink.get())

app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please try to reduce this code down to a [mcve]. If the question is about getting the value out of an entry, we don't need a canvas or  half a dozen buttons to reproduce the problem.

Comment: i done that but for some reasons the problem was resolved, so i had to make a smaller example but still include buttons

Comment: Read [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48045508/7414759) and [Tkinter understanding mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29158947/7414759)

Comment: So, you're saying if you remove just one of those buttons, the problem remains? That seems pretty unlikely. Do we have to click on all of the buttons to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

change `assign(linkentry)` and 
on your function assign just `print(link)`

Comment: sad to hear that but I tried your code and works for me, maybe you have change the function parameter. you just have to change the argument passed on the calling function inside your def taskcreator() and on your assign function print the link instead

Comment: could you send me a copy of your working one please

Comment: `def taskcreator():
    global screen
    screen = Tk()
    thelink = StringVar()
    screen.geometry('720x640')
    Label(screen, text='Enter Shoe Link').place(x=10, y=20)
    linkentry = Entry(screen, textvariable=thelink)
    linkentry.place(x=10, y=40)
    you = Button(screen, text='End Task', command=lambda: assign(linkentry)) #linkentry
    you.pack()
    screen.mainloop()

def assign(thelink):
    link = thelink.get()

    # print(llink.get())
    print(link) #print link`

Comment: up voteeeeee plssss:DDDD hahahaha justkidding always welcome:))

Comment: it is the up arrow on the left side of my answer, I believe it gives reputation